# Уместо на ли сделать задачу-парсинг через rake для сайта на rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, rake

Имеется сайт на Ruby on rails. Мне необходимо парсить сайт и результат помещать в БД. Уместно ли писать код для этого используя пользовательские задачи rake?

Как я это вижу:

1. Выполняться эта задача будет время от времени, поэтому для начала подойдет ручной запуск задачи rake из консоли.
2. В мануале написано что в rake файлах выполняется любой ruby-код, поэтому я смогу подключить nokogiri и добавлять результат в БД примерно как в seeds.rb

Правильно ли я определился с инструментарием? Есть ли вариант организовать парсинг более правильно? Можно ли запускать rake таски по заданной дате / времени, как в crontab например, и как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Можно все, но зачем?

Comment: И еще можно принимать ответы за верные, не подождав, когда появятся альтернативные ответы -- очень мотивирует...

Comment: Можно ведь и переответить. Подсказали еще гемов https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал один проект на руби и именно так и сделал. То есть, отдельная задача, которая себе делает обновление базы. Более того, я использовал nokogiri и все прекрасно работало.

rake можно запускать кроном и я не вижу особых проблем. Единственное, что нужно помнить, что cron запускает не от имени текущего пользователя (но это можно настроить) и если что то сильно завязано на домашний каталог (или подобное), то может не работать. Но это уже специфика cron'а, а не руби. И любой, маломальский системный администратор поможет справиться с ними.